# Careers doesn't allow Github Organization Repos

Tags: support, jobs, github

I've got a repo that I contribute to within an Organization that I administer. I'm trying to add it to careers, but it won't allow it. Is this on purpose? I don't really want to fork it to my personal account, since I won't be maintaining it from there.

Comment: This might have been more appropriate to post to [meta.se]...but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cupcake is correct, MSE is the meta site for Careers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard shouldn't we burninate the [careers tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/careers/info) on MSO then?

Comment: @Cupcake no, it's still useful for the careers team to come have a look and migrate to MSE if needed. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're a public member of a Github organization, you can add projects from it.

But if your membership of the organization is not public, we won't be able to see that you're a member.

You can change your visibility from the organization admin page on Github.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea I was private by default. Good to know.

Comment: FYI, if you are not an organization admin, to make your membership public go to the organization's page, people, and in your profile's show click "make public".